# What is best way to download multiple images from server and keeping them in case the orientation changes

Tags: android

I am to download multiple images(about 30-50) from server.

```
I do not need to store them permanently. My purpose is just to show the images at runtime as they are fetched and when the orientation changes the images should not be gone.
```

For orientation change purpose, i was saving all the images in Bundle,But due to limited size of bundle i faced some problems. Help! How to resolve this.

```
Should i use Memory cache.If yes, then How?
```

Comment: caching all image locally is ok, but inside application memory not recommended while changes orientation

Comment: @Sameer So what should i do? Please tell me the starategy do deal with it.

Comment: Save images in sdcard and save only data (i.e url) while changes orientation so that you do not need to make network connection again

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is to retain your fragment on configuration change. As I don't know what you are building and there is no code provided, I can't help with your implementation.

I can supply some links that have helped me to deal with similar considerations in my own apps.

[android design patterns](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

[android-er blog](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/retain-fragment-instance-across.html)

And should you decide to cache your bitmaps and retain instance state:

[android - caching bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Comment: I am loading images from server(For a social app And the activity displays the posted images by user) And downloading from server in a AsyncTask. Now, i want to retain the images for the orientation change purpose. Any idea except bundle will help me..

Comment: Ok you need to save these images, this post is old but could help you! - http://www.curious-creature.org/category/android/page/2/